# Cache Busting CSS Background Image URLs with Native CSS

Tags: css, caching

I think the answer to this might be just flat out "No.", but is there a way to cache bust a CSS `background-image` that uses a `url` with just native CSS?

For example, is there a way to make:

```
background-image: url('Images/DontCacheThisImage.png');
```

...look like...

```
background-image: url('Images/DontCacheThisImage.png?v=1234');
```

without pre-processing the CSS file using some external framework?  At the moment, the best I can seem to do without a pre-processor is to hardcode `?v=1234` at the end of all background image url's.

Is there a better way?

Note that I am aware that I can likely solve this issue using jQuery, but I'm curious if there's a pure CSS solution.